# If $m \leq a \log m + b$, why does $m = O(\max\{a \log a, b\})$?

Tags: asymptotics

I'm found this claim in something I was reading and I'm having trouble working out the logic. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you confirm the $a \log m$ part? Is that $a \log a$, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

$m \leq a \log m + b$ **has no asymptotic behavior**. This is because regardless of constants $a, b$, the left hand side grows faster than the right side, leaving only a finite range where $m$ is valid.

It is likely what was meant is $m \leq a \log a + b$. In this case we have that $m$ is bounded by something, so $m = O(a \log a + b)$. If you have that $O(x + y) = O(\max(x, y))$, then the question is solved.

But why is $O(x + y) = O(\max(x, y))$ true? With big-$O$ notation we are interested in the *asymptotically fastest growing part*. We ignore constant factors. Now check three cases (in the limit):

$$x < y \rightarrow O(x + y) = O(y)$$
$$x > y \rightarrow O(x + y) = O(x)$$
$$x = y \rightarrow O(x + y) = O(x + x) = O(2x) = O(x)$$

Since our choice for $x = y$ doesn't matter, we can see that choosing the minimum gives us the right asymptotic behavior.

Comment: Since the result is $O(\max(a\log a, b))$ is guess that $a,b$ are not constants. It's not entirely clear, though.